# Why onCreate is called twice when fire intent from current Activity?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-orientation

I am working a module where I need to open the YouTube video in the YouTube app.

I have a home screen where there is large amount of data is available in the scrollview, When I scroll down and click on any video, intent is fired to another activity where I opened the YouTube app programmatically.

Now the problem is the moment I fire intent from home activity to another activity which has YouTube app logic to play the YouTube video, Video starts playing in landscape mode. But when I finish the YouTube app, my home screen oncreate() is called again and hence I lost my onscroll position of scrollview in the home screen.

How can I handle such situation when onCreate is called twice and how can I retain my scrolled position of scrollview in the home screen?

Comment: post some code,.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal, complete example which illustrates the problem.

Comment: oaky, let me put some code

Comment: You should be able to store some scrollOffset value into `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: Why are you confused that `onCreate` is called after you move away from an activity? That is part of the lifecycle... https://developer.android.com/guide/components/images/activity_lifecycle.png

Answer (score 2):

You should not be confused with this behavior as **it is the normal Android Activity lifecycle**. You are calling Activity B from Activity A. Now, when coming back from B to A, there can be two situations -

1) **The Activity A is destroyed** due to lack of memory and it needs to be created again, thus onCreate() is called again.

2) **The Activity A is not destroyed** by the system and it is still in memory. In this case, onResume() will be called.

You will lose the position only in the first case when the activity is destroyed.

You can **save the position in a Bundle**,

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putIntArray("SCROLL_POSITION",
            new int[]{ mScrollView.getScrollX(), mScrollView.getScrollY()});
}
```

and restore it again,

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    final int[] position = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("SCROLL_POSITION");
    if(position != null)
        mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mScrollView.scrollTo(position[0], position[1]);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Thank you Aritra for answering but still facing the same problem. Actually its the screen orientation which causing trouble for me.

Comment: But you didn't mention about the screen orientation. Even if it a config change, you can still use this approach to restore the scroll state if you implement it properly.